# Algorithm to seed a cash register drawer

Tags: algorithms

Not looking for code, just a general solution or pointers in the right direction. I think that my problem can be adapted into an instance of the knapsack problem. I made an attempt at it, but couldn't figure out something that worked. (I can elaborate on this more if necessary.)

#### Concrete scenario

The actual scenario is to seed a cash register drawer with bills for the day. (The seed is the initial cash in the drawer used to make change.) The drawers are seeded every day to a specific amount. \$200.00 or \$100.00 in my case depending on the drawer. The business rule that I must follow is to maximize the number of bills available to the cashiers to make change with.

#### Problem

I need to transform an array of integers (values can be repeated, but will always be greater than or equal to 1) into another array of integers so that the sum of the result array is exactly equal to a given target value and so that the length of the result array is maximized.

Input: array of integers, target value
Output: array of integers (with maximal length and a sum exactly equal to target value.)

Comment: Another reasonable output format would be the number of bills of any given type.

Comment: For small numbers, you can solve this using dynamic programming.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Yes the input and output format are both mappings from bill type to bill count. I have a (maybe?) working solution that operates directly on those mappings, but I am not sure of the correctness of my solution. Are there any specific DP algorithms that my problem could be adapted to?